# Draw Polyline With Border Mapbox, iOS

Tags: swift, border, mapbox, polyline

I'm using Mapbox iOS SDK and trying to draw a polyline without geojson. I tried to get the route with this method:

```
func calculateRoute() {

    ...

    let options = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [origin, destination], profileIdentifier: .automobileAvoidingTraffic)
    Directions.shared.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in 
        guard let route = routes?.first else { return }
        self.showPreview(route: route)
    }
}
```

Then I tried to draw a route.

```
func showPreview(route: Route) {

    guard let steps = route.legs.first?.steps else { return }
    var points = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
    for step in steps {
        points.append(step.maneuverLocation)
    }
    let line = MGLPolyline(coordinates: &points, count: UInt(points.count))
    mapView?.addAnnotation(line)
}
```

It draws a polyline on the map view. I could change the color and the width of the polyline with two delegate methods (MGLMapViewDelegate):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, lineWidthForPolylineAnnotation annotation: MGLPolyline) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, strokeColorForShapeAnnotation annotation: MGLShape) -> UIColor {
    return .blue
}
```

but I can't find a method to set a border width and border color around the polyline. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like I had a similar use case to you (i.e. not using geojson) and ended up with something like this. By associating your route with an `MGLLineStyleLayer` you can control the visual parameters of the line.

```
func showPreview(route: Route) {
    guard route.coordinateCount > 0 else { return }
    // Convert the route’s coordinates into a polyline
    var routeCoordinates = route.coordinates!
    let polyline = MGLPolylineFeature(coordinates: &routeCoordinates, count: route.coordinateCount)

    // If there's already a route line on the map, reset its shape to the new route
    if let source = mapView.style?.source(withIdentifier: "route-source") as? MGLShapeSource {
        source.shape = polyline
    } else {
        let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "route-source", features: [polyline], options: nil)

        // Customize the route line color and width
        let lineStyle = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "route-style", source: source)
        lineStyle.lineColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.blue)
        lineStyle.lineWidth = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 3)

        // Add the source and style layer of the route line to the map
        mapView.style?.addSource(source)
        mapView.style?.addLayer(lineStyle)
    }
}
```

You want to add a border and control how that looks. If you take a look at this example on the Mapbox website: [Line style Example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/runtime-add-line/) they do what you want by creating a second `MGLLineStyleLayer` and inserting it below the first one. They call the second layer `casingLayer`. This is their code so you can see it is formed the same way as the first layer.

```
let casingLayer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "polyline-case", source: source)
    // Add your formatting attributes here. See example on website.
```

Then they insert it below the first line and because it has a wider width, shows as a border.

```
style.insertLayer(casingLayer, below: lineStyle)
```

Hope this helps.